# Returning a default value from a discord.py converter

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord channel converter

```py
class Channel(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):

        # Do converter stuff to get a channel
        # This may fail meaning that the result is not a TextChannel 

        if not isinstance(result, discord.TextChannel):
            return ctx.channel
        else:
            return result
```

As you can see I return `ctx.channel` (the channel this was invoked in) if I couldn't get the channel.
The problem is that if I do something like this....

```py
    @commands.command(name='invite', aliases=['inv'])
    @commands.guild_only()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def invite(self, ctx, channel: converters.Channel, member: discord.User):
        # Command stuff here
```

If the member runs the command with `g/invite #channel @member` it works fine, but if they run the command with `g/invite @member` then the current channel is used as a channel but the member is totally disregarded. Is there a way to stop this from happening?
(So that the channel would be the current channel but the member would be the member they mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use an [`Optional` converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-optional), then replace `None` with `ctx.channel` in the body of your callback

```
from discord import TextChannel, User
from typing import Optional

@commands.command(name='invite', aliases=['inv'])
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def invite(self, ctx, channel: Optional[TextChannel], member: User):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    # Command stuff here
```